# How to deploy and run my java program on a server using IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm running a data mining program using IntelliJ on my computer, but I need to run the program on a server for its larger memory and faster CPU.

My current work flow is: Write code on laptop => push code to github => pull code from github on server => compile and **debug**. I found myself wasting a lot of time during the development.

Is there a way to get my code written and compiled locally on IntelliJ(or Eclipse) and pushed to server for running directly?

Comment: Is there something you couldn't find in [IDEA docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-a-remote-server-configuration.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

In general terms, what you need to do is:

1. [Install the Intellij plugin associated with your application server.](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/enabling-application-server-integration-plugins.html)
2. [Create a run configuration associated with your app.](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-run-debug-configuration-for-application-server.html)
3. Build/deploy/debug and refine.

The secret sauce is #2 and is what @Jagermeister is alluding to.  From there you can do a plain IDE build, maven goals, ant tasks, or any external tool you care to configure.

The main thing you need to do is find the most efficient way to integrate your build workflow with Intellij.  If you're using simple IDE builds (what Intellij unfortunately calls "Make"), Intellij has built-in facilities for deploying "exploded" artifacts (non-archived), which allows for extremely rapid debugging via "hot-swapping" of modified classes.

All of this is in [the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/working-with-application-servers.html).